# Big o notation work

Tags: big-o

i am new in time complexity using Big-O notation 
i have three examples
and i tries to figure out the Big(o)

the first example is

```
 sum = 0;
 for(i=0; i<m/3; i++){
 System.out.println(“*”);
 for(j=0; j<n; j++)
 for(k=0; k<10; k=k+2)
 sum++;
 }
```

I think this one is O(mn), first loop works m/3 times, second loop works n times, third loops works 10 times 
then  O(mn)

the second example is

```
sum = 100;
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
sum++; 
}
for(j=10; j<n; j++)
for(k=1; k<m; k*=2)
 sum++;
```

Big-O = O(log(m)), where the number of operations executed being n + ( (n - 10) * log(m) )

the third example is

```
  sum = 0;
  for(i=2; i<n; i++){
  for(j=3; j<n; j+=2){
         sum++;
  }}
 for(k=1; k<m; k*=2)
 sum++;
```

here i think Big-O = log(m)n^2 ???

is it correct???

Comment: last is `O(n^2)`, `k` loop does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is:

1. O(m/3 * n * 5) = O(mn * C) = O(mn)
2. O(n + (n - 10) * log(m)) = O(n*log(m))
3. O((n-2)*(n-3)/2 + log(m)) = O(n<sup>2</sup> + log(m)) = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Next time, please, format your code blocks defined by braces clearer.
In 3. O(n<sup>2</sup> + log(m)) → O(n<sup>2</sup>) because f(x) = x<sup>2</sup> > g(x) = log(x), when x → +∞.

**UPD**. Your code (formatted a little bit nicer):

```
sum = 0;
// let's go from inner most loop: (n - 3)/2 actions or simpler n/2 or just n
for(i=2; i<n; i++) {
    for(j=3; j<n; j+=2) {
        sum++;
    }
}
```

Because in big-O constants don't matter, i.e. O(5) = O(1) or O(18 * x<sup>5</sup>) = O(x<sup>5</sup>).
And for example that's why `log` in big-O doesn't have base: O(log<sub>2</sub>x) = O(log(x) / log(2)) = O(log(x) * Const) = O(log(x)), where `log` - is natural logarithm (base is `e`)

Let's go again:

```
sum = 0;    
// n actions in inner loop n times. So it's O(n^2)
for(i=2; i<n; i++) {
    for(j=3; j<n; j+=2) {
        sum++;
    }
}
// THEN there're another log(m) actions
for(k=1; k<m; k*=2) {
    sum++;
}
```

So we sum it: O(n<sup>2</sup> + log(m)).

Now let's [take a look](https://www.google.com/search?q=f(x)+%3D+x%5E2+and+g(x)+%3D+log(x)&oq=f(x)+%3D+x%5E2+and+g(x)+%3D+log(x)&gws_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=jp86Wt7IB4SckwXI16DYBg) to functions x<sup>2</sup> and log(x). As you see, x<sup>2</sup> grows much faster than log(x). The proof can be achieved by researching the limit of l(x) = log(x) / x<sup>2</sup>, when x → +∞. It equals zero.
That's why in the sum x<sup>2</sup> + log(x) the first term dominates. So [x<sup>2</sup> + log(x)] / x<sup>2</sup> = 1 + o-small(x), i.e. they're equal in terms of complexity. That's why O(n<sup>2</sup> + log(m)) = O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Original equation has two different variables it depends on. If they're both independent, it's better to "count" them both: O(n<sup>2</sup> + log(m)).

Comment: @Teema is there something not clear for you? I can extend explanations

Comment: @Teema , added to answer

Comment: @Pkuderov, thanks a lot dear, that is really helped me